# EKEvent AddAlarm Not Working

Tags: ios, calendar, alarm, ekevent

[Fixed] (Kind of)
Seems you can't have an alarm at the end of an event. I wanted the event to appear spanning x number of days in the calendar, then an alarm to signal when it's due to end. Seems that's not possible. Can only have alarms before the event begins. Silly apple :(

I can't seem to get alarms to save when adding new events. Here's the code...
I want the alarm to sound at the time the event occurs, I thought maybe the all-day option was messing it up but it doesn't save regardless.

Here's the code...

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];

event.title = title;
event.startDate = [global main].Entry.WithdrawalDate;
event.endDate = [global main].Entry.WithdrawalDate;
//event.allDay = YES;
event.availability = EKEventAvailabilityFree;
event.location = [global main].Holding.Name;
event.notes = [self compileNotes];

//Tried settings the array and adding to it, neither works
//NSArray *arrAlarm = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:[global main].Entry.WithdrawalDate]];
//event.alarms= arrAlarm;
EKAlarm * alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:[global main].Entry.WithdrawalDate];
[event addAlarm:alarm];


[event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
saved = [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
```

Comment: It appears that if the start & end date are the same. Then you can't set the alarm to be the same also. Setting it with an offset works...

[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600]; //1 Hour